# Azure AD Authentication Endless Loop, Err Too Many Requests

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, webforms, azure-active-directory

I built a Web Forms app in ASP.Net and I'm using Azure AD Authentication so that users can sign in with their Microsoft credentials and be properly authenticated.

I closely followed the following tutorial provided by Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp

The app is working as intended for the most part, except for one annoying issue. Users are occasionally receiving the following error message "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" "Try clearing your cookies." Clearing cookies and signing back in does solve the problem but obviously this is not ideal.

The problem is I haven't been able to reproduce the issue myself so it's hard to pinpoint what exactly is causing the issue.

I have a Master Page and in the codebehind I'm running the following code to make sure the user is authenticated while navigating the app

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Check if user is authenticated on each page request
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/home.aspx" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    //Check if connection string is set
                    if (Session["ConnectionString"].ToString() == "")
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("home.aspx"); //If empty redirect user to Home page to set connection string
                    }

                    //Get data for current user and display their username and email address
                    ClaimsPrincipal cp = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
                    userName.InnerText = cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value + " " + cp.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
                    email.InnerText = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                } 
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }  
        }
```

In the WebConfig file I have the Redirect URL set as

```
<add key="RedirectUrl" value="https://mywebsite.com/auth/openid/return" />
```

and in Azure Portal I used this same RedirectUrl

Any idea what may be causing the occasional issue of infinite loop that users are getting?

Comment: Please use the same RedirectUrl in your web.config file and Master Page file.